# raspberry x264 compilation issues

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi

for  Raspberry pi which is as follows:

```
cd /my/path/where/i/keep/my/source/code
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --cross-prefix=${CCPREFIX} --prefix=/my/path/were/i/keep/built/arm/stuff
make
make install
```

when i did this, i got some message as:

> You specified a pre-ARMv6 or Thumb-1 CPU in your CFLAGS.
>   If you really want to run on such a CPU, configure with --disable-asm.

how to do this .. i am going to use this all on raspberry Pi which uses ARM 11 processor

Comment: run ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --cross-prefix=${CCPREFIX} --prefix=/ --disable-asm

Answer (score 0):

> i am going to use this all on raspberry Pi which uses ARM 11 processor

Note that ARM versioning is not the same as ARM architecture. The ARM11 *chip* was the first to use ARMv6 *architecture*.

Anyways, as [Ottavio Campana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795910/ottavio-campana) said in that comment, this message is just warning you that you missed a switch. Add --disable-asm to the end of the command you used before and see what happens.